# How to append the streaming log data into an hdfs file in Flume? Does anyone have the MR source code to append the data to a file in hdfs

Tags: streaming, hdfs, flume

I need to append the streaming data into hdfs using Flume. Without overwriting the existing log file I need to append the streaming data to existing file in hdfs. Could you please provide links for the MR code for the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? It always helps if you can demonstrate the legwork you've done before asking the SO community to do work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Flume does not overwrite existing data in hdfs directory by default. It is because, flume save incoming data with folder name appended sink timestamp, such as
*Flume.2345234523* so if you  run flume again in the same directory in hdfs it will create another file, under the same hdfs path.

Comment: Hi Farslan, Data is being ingested continuously like log files in the local file system and it needs to be loaded to hdfs using flume. Data needs to be reflected in hdfs file in real time.

Comment: Flume can reads log file from any source and then load to hdfs. If you want to append specific file in hdfs you can configure it from sink. A hdfs file can take data as much as you defined, for example `hdfs.rollSize= 1024`, this file load 1024 MB data. Overall, you  flume load file to hdfs it is automatically crates files under specified directory, when you read this file from hive you can just give parent folders path.

Comment: Hi, I need to configure **FTP SERVER** containing text files as source and i need to configure it as source to Flume. Could you tell about the configurations that are need to be set for FTP Source and HDFS sink for the streaming text data.

Comment: `agent.sources.ftp1.type = org.keedio.flume.source.ftp.source.Source

  agent.sources.ftp1.client.source = ftp

  agent.sources.ftp1.name.server = 127.0.0.1
  agent.sources.ftp1.user = username
  agent.sources.ftp1.password = password
  agent.sources.ftp1.port = 21`

Comment: #an example of ftp1 sink can look like this
agent.sinks.ftp1.channel = ftp1
agent.sinks.ftp1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.path = <your hdfs path>
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.inUsePrefix = Ftp
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.rollCount = 100
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0

Comment: `agent.channels = ftp1
agent.sources = ftp1
agent.sinks = ftp1

Comment: Hi, here is nice writing for you.
   
`agent.channels = ftp1
agent.sources = ftp1 
agent.sinks = ftp1
agent.sources.ftp1.type = org.keedio.flume.source.ftp.source.Source agent.sources.ftp1.client.source = ftp 
agent.sources.ftp1.name.server = 127.0.0.1 
agent.sources.ftp1.user = username 
agent.sources.ftp1.password = password 
agent.sources.ftp1.port = 21`

Comment: `agent.sinks.ftp1.channel = ftp1
agent.sinks.ftp1.type = hdfs 
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.path = <your hdfs path> 
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.inUsePrefix = Ftp 
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.rollCount = 100 
agent.sinks.ftp1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0`

Comment: you can get this  udf ftp project from github *[link][1]*


  [1]: https://github.com/keedio/flume-ftp-source